# Cannot get Entity Framework 5 and Power Tools to work correctly with Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, frameworks, entity

I know this question is similar to another one, but I have now tried both the Oracle data provider and the Devart (dotConnect) provider, and cannot get either combination to work well with our Oracle 11g database and the Power Tools "reverse engineer code first" feature.

With the Oracle provider, there was no way to specify a schema or subset of the database, and it cranked out almost 3,000 entity classes, even though the connection was specific to the target application.  It grabbed all the Oracle system tables, etc., along with the application data tables.

With the Devart provider, I still could not specify WHAT to generate, and ended up having to kill it off after running for almost a day.

Anyone know how to get this stuff working with Oracle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have answered you about dotConnect for Oracle (Entity Developer) at http://forums.devart.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=27520.